# Why do the colors of these buttons look off?

Tags: color, color-theory, critique, button

I'm learning graphic design and, for practice, I'm making an app. I noticed my color choice of these buttons look off, although I'm unsure why. Also the proportions, but I'll take care of that later. Could you provide a critique of why these colors don't seem to go well?

[image]

Comment: Start with a smaller number of colors

Comment: Contrast between the background colors should also be improved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using four different hues of green, all of them very saturated. This makes them clash with each other. Also, the contrast between the yellow and the soft green in the background is very low, and both colours are, again, very saturated.

A good way of making a colour palette is to use [the HSB model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), where colours are quantified using values for Hue, Saturation, and Brightness. The trick is to reduce the amount of different Hues as much as possible. With just a few Hue values chosen, create a colour palette by varying Saturation and Brightness only. Do note that this always leaves greyscale colours available.

Also, make sure that neigbouring colours have enough contrast. Either in Hue, Saturation, or Brightness, or in more than one.

My suggestion here would be to select only a *single* hue, a green, and use a saturated and bright colour only for the most important element. Use lower saturation for all the rest, and increase the amount of light greys and whites.